# How to call Method with optional parameters using reflections c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reflection

I'm calling a methods using reflections. However due to some requirement one of the method parameters are changed and keeping new parameters as optional parameters.
here is code

```
Void Method1(string request, string constants, string count = null)

Void Method2(string request, string constants)
```

In Method1 count parameter is **optional**.For the above methods, I'm calling using reflections
Here is the code :

```
result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] {request, constants});
```

I have tried with below approach but getting exception

```
result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] {request, constants ,System.Type.Missing});
```

Got below exception for **Method2** the above code is working for **Method1**

> Parameter count mismatch.

Please suggest me for optional parameters in method using reflections

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional parameters: aren't actually optional - all that happens is that the compiler normally supplies the omitted value automatically for you. Since you're not *using* a compiler here, you'll need to supply it yourself, using `new object[] {request, constants, null}`. Note that if you want to properly respect the default value (rather than knowing it is `null` in this case), you'd need to look at the `ParameterInfo`, specifically `.HasDefaultValue` and `.DefaultValue`.

Example (not using `ParameterInfo`, note):

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string request = "r", constants = "c", count = "#";
        var classInstance = new P();

        typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Method1),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { request, constants, null });

        typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Method1),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { request, constants, count });

        typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Method2),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { request, constants });
    }

    void Method1(string request, string constants, string count = null)
        => Console.WriteLine($"#1: {request}, {constants}, {count}");

    void Method2(string request, string constants)
        => Console.WriteLine($"#2: {request}, {constants}");
}
```

Comment: ,Thank you for immediate response. I have tried by giving the new object[] {request, constants, null} still I'm facing same error **Parameter count mismatch.** for **Method2**.Could you please guide me .

Comment: @prasanthi I've added examples of calling both methods; if you can't get your version working, please post a minimal repro similar to what I have above, that shows what you're seeing. It is hard to debug code that only exists on someone else's computer.